# Can't get nav bar to appear in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried everything to get my nav bar to appear along with my about and home page.

When I use the following code, even though I am certain my css is working, I cannot get a nav bar to appear. All that happens is my 'about' link goes to the far right, and my 'home' goes to the left, but there is no nav bar to be seen.

Does anyone know why my nav bar css is not activating? Even though all of the other bootstrap css is functional?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Attempting to get nav bar to work</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class='navbar navbar-default'>
      <a href='../' class='navbar-brand'>
        Home
      </a>
      <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>
        About
      </ul>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's an invalid HTML. Where did you get that from? Bootstrap provides sample navbar codes. Use that.

Comment: I got it straight from bootstrap

Comment: Check the answer mate, in full screen. See if that suits you, then try to copy the code and put it in the answer. Your code is totally wrong man. Definitely, I will say, you haven't taken it from Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so this is what I get from Bootstrap and it is totally different from what you have got:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Home</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="./">Default <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Static top</a></li>
        <li><a href="../navbar-fixed-top/">Fixed top</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Check out the snippet in full screen.

Comment: You are getting your source straight from the site itself. Perhaps the nav-bar in the folders that I downloaded are different?

Comment: I downloaded Bootstrap folder from their site.

Comment: @ironSteel Right agreed, see if this suits you, then try to copy the code and put it in the answer. Your code is totally wrong man. Definitely, I will say, you haven't taken it from Bootstrap. Make sure you follow the same logic, `ul > li > a` and the classes. And you should be alright.

Comment: @ironSteel Also it is better to use CDN instead of downloading the full BS library. It is much faster and keeps your code clean as well.

Comment: Thanks man. Perhaps it is because I was not using the <li> element under the <ul> element, even though the tutorial I followed told me to only use the <ul> element and forego the <li>. So my about link, is way to the far right and all wonky, followed by no nav-default which should be appearing.

Comment: @ironSteel That's totally wrong man, you cannot have anything other than `<li>` inside `<ul>`. Get rid of the tutorial that you are following, it is totally wrong.